# Get Region info of Moldova

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

I'm trying to obtain region info by ISO 3166-1 TwoLetters country name - "MD".

```
var r = new RegionInfo("MD");
```

But I'm obtaining the following exception:

> Culture name 'MD' is not supported.

This is strange because Microsoft Table of supported countries Moldova is present:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374073.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation on RegionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atwc2921.aspx) about the cultures names:

> The predefined culture names are listed in the National Language Support (NLS) API Reference at the Go Global Developer Center.

When you go to [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx), `MD` is not found in there.

Answer (score 3):

You may [create your own culture info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Run Visual Studio as Administrator. In your project, add a reference to **sysglobl**.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cib = null;
        try
        {
            // Create a CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder 
            // object named "ro-MD".
            cib = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(
                                    "ro-MD", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);

            // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder 
            // object with culture information.
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ro-RO");
            cib.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);

            // Populate the new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder 
            // object with region information.
            RegionInfo ri = new RegionInfo("RO");
            cib.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(ri);

            var filePath = "ro-MD.xml";

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                File.Delete(filePath);

            // Save as XML
            cib.Save(filePath);

            // TODO: modify the XML
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
            var ns = 
                "http://schemas.microsoft.com/globalization/2004/08/carib/ldml";

            xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("regionEnglishName", ns))
                .FirstOrDefault().Attribute("type").SetValue("Moldova");

            xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("regionNativeName", ns))
                .FirstOrDefault().Attribute("type").SetValue("Moldova");

            // and so on
            xDoc.Save(filePath);

            var roMd = CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder
                .CreateFromLdml(filePath);

            // this may throw an exception if the culture info exists 
            try
            {
                CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister("ro-MD");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //throw;
            }

            // Register the custom culture.
            roMd.Register();

            // Display some of the properties of the custom culture.
            var riMd = new RegionInfo("ro-MD");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll just have to take care of the XML modification.

*Note: It seems that you may also save the culture without administrative privileges. Here's a reference: [How to: Save Custom Cultures Without Administrative Privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404375%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I haven't tested it myself, but the only comment on that article seems to suggest it doesn't work.*

**[UPDATE]**

This is also an interesting approach (a wrapper for invoking native methods):

[Get the full list of Windows supported countries with C#](http://ucodia.fr/2011/09/csharp-get-list-windows-countries/).

Answer (score 0):

System.Globalization.RegionInfo uses the culture data and if there is no culture data with that region, then it will not succeed. That is also why creating a custom culture for a language with that region will cause it to succeed.

What you probably want instead is to use the new [Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.geographicregion.aspx) which does support all the current ISO-3166 countries.

Or you can p/Invoke into GetGeoInfo and EnumSystemGeoId as they support Moldova as indicated in the documentation you reference above.